# Hide navigation bar, android 4.2+

Tags: android, navigation, hide

Is it possible to hide navigation bar on e.g. tablets in activity, so it does not appear when user is clicking on the screen?
I want it to appear only when user is swiping from bottom to middle of the screen, just like in e.g. Real Racing 3.
When I use:

```
    myView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Unfortunetly navigation bar is hidden, but when user is clicking, it appears again. I want it to work only with this swipe gesture. How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a platform behavior. Apps do not have the sort of control of the navigation bar that you are looking for, and for good reason. All it takes is one app not implementing a way to show the nav bar and the user is stuck. You will have to design your app with the platform's behavior in mind.